# What to do with batch size when TensorFlow says "there could be performance gains if more memory is available"

Tags: python, performance, gpu, tensorflow

I have got the following error trying to increase the `batch_size` for a CNN model on an Nvidia K80:

`2017-08-07 20:33:38.573318: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.04GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.`

I would like to know what's the fastest option when encountering this situation:

- Do nothing and let the model train despite the warning.
- Scale down the batch size and learning rate by a factor, but do more iterations by the same factor so as to give the same results with a lower batch size and more iterations (following the **Linear Scaling Rule** as discussed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02677.pdf)).

Comment: Training efficiency due to increasing batch size is always sublinear (ie, 2x larger batch size needs more than 0.5x iterations). So if increasing the batch size doesn't give super-linear increase in throughput, it's a net loss. So the thing to do is to see how your throughput is affected, ie, stop increasing the batch size once your training throughput starts curving downward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you continue with the training (first bullet above), you will experience some loss of efficiency as the OS swaps your data in and out (thrashing).  Option 2 is the correct one (in my experience): reduce the batch size to make efficient use of available memory, and increase the iterations to compensate.

The critical training volume is measured in epochs, not iterations.  If you reduce the batch size by 2x, then you increase iterations by 2x, and you get nearly identical results.

Comment: Thanks. By iteration, I mean something like `steps_per_epoch`. I guess that works too... right? BTW, what do you mean exactly by critical training volume, do you mean total training volume? So, basically, if I split in half the `batch_size`, I should train on the same number of examples by doubling the number of `steps_per_epoch`, where at every step I feed in a `batch_size` amount of examples. What do you think of that exactly?

Comment: (and that, knowing the fact that the relationship is not exactly linear, but very close to linear)

Comment: You have this correct: I used "critical" in its common sense, to imply total training volume.  Yes, steps_per_epoch is where you define that.  I always find this parameter name counter-intuitive, since it's derived from epoch (an independently defined term) and the batch size.

Comment: The relationship is, indeed, only *close* to linear.  However, linear provides a very good approximation.  My approach had been to let it run a little long and watch the testing accuracy.